# logstash-snmptrap not showing any logs in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, net-snmp, snmptrapd

We are trying to implement logstash with snmptrap, but the logs are not coming in logstash, in netstat the logstash udp port is not open for all can that be the issue.

logstash.conf

```
input {
  snmptrap {
   type => "snmptrap"
   community => "public"
   port => "1062"
 }
}
```

snmptrapd.conf

```
authCommunity log,net public
forward default localhost:1062
```

Is there any issue with the configuration ? Netstat output

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:162                 0.0.0.0:*                               
udp        0      0 :::1062                     :::*
```

Comment: What's the Logstash output configuration? You're only showing your input configuration.

Comment: @MagnusBäck   input {
  snmptrap {
    type => "snmptrap"
    community => "public"
    port => "1062"
  }
}


output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}

Comment: @MagnusBäck : We were able to make it work by achanging the port in client side, our bad, thanks anyways. Need to ask you though, is there anyway to translate snmptrap output for logstash

Comment: Judging by [its documentation](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/snmptrap) it places text in the message field so you should be able to use standard filters like grok to parse it into fields.